# When should I use $rootScope?

Tags: angularjs

I was reading a discussion about using `$rootScope` to share some data across all application.

http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Using-rootScope-store-data-5010991.S.5848794319187644420?view=&srchtype=discussedNews&gid=5010991&item=5848794319187644420&type=member&trk=eml-anet_dig-b_pd-ttl-cn&fromEmail=&ut=36igDbZcDcIC81

Some people said that this is a bad practice, and that we should use our own *services* to store that kind of data.

Although I'm willing to agree, I have a question: isn't `$rootScope` a native *service* of AngularJS? When should I use `$rootScope` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment of Kibsaim in the said thread:

```
Hello Carla, 

I will recommend not overloading rootScope, although what you comment can be done, I will       
recommend you using a service with state, and inject it over controllers to share the   
information. 

That should be cleaner on the long run.
```

Putting objects in the `$rootScope` is bad in the long run in the same way that polluting Javascript's global namespace is bad.